# email a database made by My SQL

Tags: mysql

I want to email a MYSQL database I created with all tables and queries to other person to check do I use the Import and Export Wizard or there are other ways?

Comment: how is what you are going to do with the database dump relevant to how you generate a database dump? Just use mysqldump and zip/gzip/bzip2 the result. If by import export wizard you mean phpmyadmin - you're asking the wrong question in the wrong place.

Comment: what you actually wants..??structure of all tables that you have created..?or you want the database dump..?

Comment: Hi Sylvia, can you clarify your question regarding what OS you are running on, what version of MySQL and also what program you have an 'import and export wizard' in?

Comment: This question isn't clear enough as it stands

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question I am answering on that basis.
If you want database dump use `mysqldump` client utility.You can Execute it as

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --all-databases > db_dump.sql
```

where `db_dump.sql` is file which contains your table structure and data being inserted to it.For various other options of `mysqldump` use `mysqldump --help`

If you only wants the structure of your tables then write Command as

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --no-data --databases db1 db2 db3  > db_structure.sql
```

For more information about mysqldump please visit [The Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

If you asking any other thing please clearly update with your question.

Answer (score -1):

you can use phpmyadmin to export database. alternative , if you familiar with cli , use mysqldump to export your database schema .I guess that what you asked .

Answer (score -1):

[SQLyog](http://webyog.com/en/) - MySQL GUI has a tool called SQL Scheduler & Reporting tool. You would need to specify a query and the result of this query will be emailed by the tool. Although this feature is available only in the paid version, I guess there is a trial version available. You might want to give it a shot.

Comment: Why was this post down-voted?????